# Importing C++ Files into Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse, import, helios

I'm having trouble importing source code into my Eclipse console. I'm running Helios on a Mac, and I imported the files using <kbd>File->Import->Import</kbd> existing code as makefile. The files all imported, but there is no debug or includes files, so the #includes in the header are not functioning properly.

[Here's a screeny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NExwm.png):

[image]